# Reasons not to set onclick attribute within html tags

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'am using php to echo certain contents, with attribute:

```
onclick="example()",
```

so I don't have to append a click listener one by one to each elements with javascript.

Somewhen, somewhere I read that it is a bad practice to declare onclick within html tags. I'd like to know if it's true, and the reasons why?

Comment: Good question, but not sure it's on topic here.

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns

Comment: For the same reason you don't want to add inline css in your markup. Keep the styles in an separate and self contained css file?